# Why does sunlight on these windows form caustics with a seemingly hyperbolic pattern?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I noticed these caustics outside my office about a month ago and took pictures: one facing towards the sun and one facing towards the reflective surface (a set of double-paned windows).

The seemingly-hyperbolic form of these caustics really captured my attention, and in searching I stumbled on *[catastrophe theory](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Catastrophe.html)*. Apparently there are seven types of catastrophe (for systems with less than four variables.)

I'd really like to learn more about how these kinds of patterns are generated, but I don't know how to get started with the math. **Can anyone explain what type of catastrophe that would result in this pattern?**

[image: caustics]

Comment: Are the windows flat? As I see them they are not flat, but they are like a bowl. They are bent in or outwards?

Comment: I don't recall that they were curved when I looked at them up close, but I do think you're right: in the left image the horizon forms a upward-facing "U" shape, which suggests to me that the outer window was (at the time) a slightly concave 'bowl-like' shape.